# Have the Spider-Man sketches from The Electric Company ever been referenced in more "canonical" media?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

In the 1970s, the Children's Television Workshop produced a show called *The Electric Company*, aimed at improving reading skills for elementary school students.  It featured many recurring sketches, and along with the superheroes such as Letterman and the Six Dollar and Nineteen Cent Man, it featured short sketches with Spider-Man interacting with various characters from the show and strange [super-villains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gA_Hs9DkmOo).  The reading gimmick was that all of Spidey's dialogue was presented in the form of speech balloons, which the viewers had to decode for themselves.

What I am now wondering is whether any of the characters or incidents made up for *The Electric Company* were ever referred to in other media:  comics, movies, or whatever.

Comment: This is impressive and horrifying at the same time. I'm horripressed.

Comment: I am a life-long Spider-Man fan, and honestly, these sketches are ultimately the reason why.

Comment: And yes, that deep voice introducing the video is indeed... Morgan Freeman.

Comment: I could have sworn he showed up in one of the crossover games or comics...

Comment: @Buzz Me too. I still hum that song sometimes. Wait. What if this is the secret reason why Morgan Freeman's voice is so compelling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spidey_Super_Stories), Marvel did a comic book series entitled *Spidey Super Stories* that used this character and a record was also released.

Also, in the Spiderverse crossover, Spidey references someone who was likely supposed to be the Electric Company version.

> "This one spider-man just kept trying to teach me the alphabet."